# Set source file dependencies in csproj file without manually editing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

I want to group all the files of my partial classes similar to the way that myForm.cs, myForm.resx, and myForm.Designer.cs are.  I can do this by manually editing the csproj file and adding DependentUpon elements to the files, but can I do it using the GUI instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no intrinsic way in the IDE to perform this, but it looks like someone has [an add in available](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DependentUponAdd-in.aspx) that does what you want.

Also worthwhile mentioning [Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/) which allows you to group these Solution Explorer dependencies in your tabs as well (so you can have all related files open without losing a lot of screen/tab space real estate).